# VirtualBox working but "/sbin/vboxconfig" is missing

Tags: virtualbox

I had an older version of VirtualBox running (6.1.16), and installed VirtualBox 6.1.26 with:

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-dkms
```

I launched VirtualBox from the command line, and things went OK, but `/sbin/vboxconfig` does not exist.

Is this a one-time/normal thing?

VBoxManage exists, which is the important thing, I would think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a problem that I've seen too often with VirtualBox, but there are instances when an installation will "hiccup". The `/sbin/vboxconfig` file is just a symbolic link, so you can resolve it yourself if you'd like:

0. Open Terminal (if it's not already open)
1. Create the symbolic link:

   ```
   sudo ln -s /usr/lib/virtualbox/postinst-common.sh /sbin/vboxconfig
   ```

   <sup>**Note:** The use of `sudo` here ensures the link can be written and is owned by `root`.</sup>

Be sure that all of the VirtualBox packages are running with the same version number to reduce the risk of errors, particularly with the "Guest Additions CD Image".